# Detect IE version from Apache, in case of compatibility mode

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, http, browser, http-headers

> If a webpage is retrieved from a website in the Local intranet zone, IE7 mode is used. -[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955410%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

So that's what happening with us. Client has set the option to "open intranet sites in compatibility mode". So at their place our application loads in IE7 mode.

***Is there any way by which I can detect whether the client is running his IE in compatible mode?***

As far as I know if the browser is in compatible mode then it sends IE7 user-agent string to Apache. So I can get that document mode is IE7, but I can't verify whether it's his native IE7 or the compatible one.

Anyone has any idea on ***how to detect the exact IE browser version from Apache and to detect whether it is in compatible mode or native mode***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are user agent strings for IE that show the compatibility modes.

```
IE7: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1;...)
IE8: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0;...)
IE8 Compatibility View: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0;...)
IE9: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
IE9 Compatibility View: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0;...)
IE10 Compatibility View Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0;...
IE11 Compatibility View : Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0...)
```

The way to determine if it is `native IE7` or `8` and `9` running in compatibility mode is that IE8 and IE9 will also contain the `Trident` string.

So if you do a user_agent check in apache, for `MSIE 7.0` and it also contains `Trident/4.0` Then it's `IE8` running in `IE7 compatibility mode`.

Same with `IE9`. If it has both `MSIE 7.0` and `Trident/5.0` then it's `IE9` running in IE7 compatibility mode.

Otherwise, it the user_agent string only has `MSIE 7.0` then it's native IE7.

That is probably the only way by user_agent. Hope that helps.

More info here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx

Also here is a nice list too.
http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/

Comment: Then what does `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)` mean?

Comment: That could have been a preview version or something. IE10 user agent string is `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0;...` for compatiblity mode. see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx#user-agent_changes_in_earlier_versions