# Conditional script/style coding

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, compatibility

I have a vendor that has been an IE only shop for the past 19 years (that I'm aware of - it might be more).  They've finally decided they want to make the numerous apps I've built for them cross-browser.  I have a lot of specialized code that's going to need to be changed, but the problem is, they're running IE in Compatibility Mode right now, so that everything works.  And Compatibility Mode screws up normal, modern CSS/Javascript/JQuery.  And I need to go through and change pages piecemeal until it's all done.

So what I need is to be able to detect compatibility mode (or IE7 mode in the HTTP Headers in some cases) and put in parallel code until we can switch it all over.  I'm using CSS expressions for heights and widths, for example.  And that works in compatibility mode, while vw and vh aren't even recognized in compatibility mode.

How do I do the conditionals, and is it different for scripts and css?

Edit: This is not about the browser treating VH and VW oddly. In compatibility mode, those things are simply gibberish.  Using XX would have the same results.

Comment: I don't envy you for the position that you're in. It sounds like https://modernizr.com/ might make your life a bit easier?

Comment: So are they dumping  the header into the page on every request?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VW not working correctly in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30985386/vw-not-working-correctly-in-ie9)

Comment: In IIS, you can add HTTP headers that are automatically sent with every page.  Yes, some of the apps are set up with EmulateIE:IE7.  But even if I remove those, the browsers themselves are set to compatibility mode.

Comment: Thanks, @AhmetZeybek, but no.  In compatibility mode, the browser simply doesn't recognize vh and vw as anything whatsoever.  I could use xx in place of them and get the same result.

Comment: If possible for you then you can try to check the user agent strings. See here: https://textuploader.com/16djm Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670467/detect-ie-version-from-apache-in-case-of-compatibility-mode If they are upgrading their old apps then it is recommended that they also use the latest browsers like MS Edge or at least the latest version of IE. The support for those older versions of IE prior to IE 11 is already ended. using those older versions may create compatibility and security issues.

Comment: Let us know about the status of the issue so that we can try to provide further suggestions. if needed.